# Qt: Objective-C header gets compiled as c++-header

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt, pimpl-idiom

I'm currently trying to implement the PIMPL-Idiom to encapsulate Objective-C functionality in a C++ class in **Qt**. My pro file looks as it follows:

```
QT += core gui
TARGET = testProject
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp Helper.cpp
HEADERS += HelperInterface.h Helper.h

OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += ObjCHelper.mm
OBJECTIVE_HEADERS += ObjCHelper.h
```

The `ObjCHelper.h` is the objective-C header

```
#import "HelperInterface.h"

@interface ObjCHelper : NSObject { int someVar }
- (int) doSomething():(void *)param;
@end
```

The `ObjCHelper.mm`

```
#import "ObjCHelper.h"

@implementation ObjCHelper
MyClassImpl::MyClassImpl() : self(NULL) { }
MyClassImpl::~MyClassImpl() {
    [(id)self dealloc];
}
void MyClassImpl::init()
{
    self = [[ObjCHelper alloc] init];
}
//...
@end
```

The class MyClassImpl is defined in HelperInterface.

---

When i try to compile this project i receive the following errors:

```
cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'ObjCHelper'
@interface ObjCHelper : NSObject
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
```

It seems to me like Qt is treating the Objective-C header file `ObjCHelper.h` as a normal c++ header file! Why is that so?

The header file `ObjCHelper.h` isn't included anywhere else than in `ObjCHelper.mm`

Answer (score 1):

Might be an instance of https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36575 , fixed by https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/77117/ in Qt 5.6.